# Python neo4j return relationship properties

Tags: python, neo4j

I'm running a pretty simple cypher query to get a mutual directed relation: `MATCH (this {name: "me"})-[r1]->(channel)<-[r2]-(target) RETURN *`. The thing is that the python driver won't give me any of the attributes on relations, but if I specify them in the RETURN it works fine, e.g. `RETURN r1.bananas`. How can I get return * to include relation attributes so I can keep the nicely nested return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the issue.
Using Python 3.8.10, neo4j 4.3.4 (pip install neo4j) and neo4j DBMS 4.3.3
I took the movie example database and ran this code:

```
with driver.session() as session:
    result = session.run("MATCH (Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->() RETURN * LIMIT 1")
    for record in result:
        pprint(record["r"]["roles"])
driver.close()
```

The output is `['Shane Falco']` which is correct (the property of the ACTED_IN relationship.

That said, I realised that RETURN * will only return "named" nodes and relationships (those that you assigned to variables).
You can see this in the table view in Neo4J Browser:
Running `MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) RETURN * LIMIT 1` will only return p and m, NOT THEIR RELATIONSHIP.